# Review a form before submitting in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, backend

I am building a registration form. I want the users to review their filled-up forms to confirm their submissions. But in my code the form is submitted twice (overwritten not duplicated). Once when they hit the submit button after filling their form and overwritten after hitting the submit button on the review page. As a result if they close the browser in the review page their page is still submitted, which I don't want to allow.

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    form = RegisterForm()
    print('hi')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            z = form.cleaned_data
            if (Register.objects.filter(email=z['email']).exists()):
                print('already exist')
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                print('xx')
                return redirect('preview', pk=z.get('id'))
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'event/index.html', context)

def preview(request, pk):
    prev = Register.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        prev.save()
        print('overwrite')
        return redirect('/')
    print('yy')
    context = { 'prev':prev,'id':pk}
    return render(request, 'event/preview.html', context)
```

## index.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Event Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mobile-screen">
        <div class="header">
        </div>

        <div class="logo"></div>

        <form id="login-form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
                {{form.name}}
                {{form.email}}
                <input class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit" value="Register" name="Register">
        </form>

      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

# Create your models here.
class Register(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Well you can add a boolean `reviewed` to your `Register`, and thus set it to `True` in case it is reviewed. Every now and then you remove the items with `review=False` that are "old".

Comment: That'll still overwrite